# Format GeoJSON coordinates with OpenLayers by easily swapping between DD, DMS, DDM natively?

Tags: openlayers

When writing GeoJSON from OpenLayers what is the default coordinate format? When writing the GeoJSON from an ExtentInteraction I get an output formatted like so:

{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-13614109.32469666,-1789063.2448918968],[-13614109.32469666,3379341.6847958053],[-6736155.0721122585,3379341.6847958053],[-6736155.0721122585,-1789063.2448918968],[-13614109.32469666,-1789063.2448918968]]]},"properties":null}]}

Apologies as I'm a complete tyro. Also, didn't see it on the Openlayers website API documentation.

Additionally, is there a way to write the GeoJSON so that the coordinates are returned in a specified format. I.e. DD, DMS, and DDM

This is how I'm writing the GeoJSON now:

```
         const extentCopy = extent.getExtent();

         new GeoJSON().writeFeatures([new Feature(fromExtent(extentCopy))]);
```

Thanks for the admonishment in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is in the view projection units.  For degrees use

```
new GeoJSON().writeFeatures(
  [new Feature(fromExtent(extentCopy))],
  {dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326', featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection()}
);
```

Comment: Thanks again @Mike.